# Should I use dispatcher.Invoke(...) or ObserveOn(dispatcher)?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I've been given some code to work on where the dispatcher is passed to the view model in its constructor. I'm now wondering if I should use `ObserveOn(dispatcher)`, or `dispatcher.Invoke(...)` when I want something to be executed on the UI thread.

For example, I could do this:

```
this.WhenAny(me => me.SomeValue, _ => Unit.Default)
.ObserveOn(dispatcher)
.Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod());

...

private void SomeMethod()
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

or I could do this:

```
this.WhenAny(me => me.SomeValue, _ => Unit.Default)
.Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod());
```

Which would then mean I could do this instead:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>{//do some stuff});
}
```

Is there any major difference between the two?

My concern is, what if I want to call SomeMethod() at some other part in the code, which isn't triggered by SomeValue changing? I'd then need to do `dispatcher.invoke(new Action(() => someMethod()));`, which makes me think using the `dispatcher.Invoke(...)` inside SomeMethod is the best option.

Is this a good or a bad move? At the minute I'm using both techniques evenly. I intend to shift to one of them, but want to know the right way first.

Comment: I would say this is a flavor question, if you have the Reactive extensions and you don't need to `Invoke()` anywhere else, why not use the extensions?  That's why it's there.  Re-factor it later if it becomes appropriate/makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would see if I could be given an instance of `IScheduler` that is an implementation of `DispatcherScheduler`. This way I would be able to test my code with a `TestScheduler` without having to get into the bowels of dispatchers and pushing frames etc. Once you have an instance of an `IScheduler` then you can just use it to `ObserveOn(dispatcherScheduler)`.

I would also agree with @mclaassen that you should know which scheduler/thread you are on and therefore whether you should need to scheduler/invoke or not. So for example, if you are observing `INotifyPropertyChanged` events then you will be on the dispatcher so no need to dispatch. If you are receiving a response from a network call or a heavy calculation then you are probably on another thread so you should schedule/dispatch to get back to the dispatcher. The cost of

The standard pattern in Rx for this is to either do no scheduling because you are on the correct thread already:

```
//this is a ViewModel, and property changes occur on the dispatcher
this.WhenAny(
    vm => vm.PropertyA, 
    vm => vm.PropertyB, 
    _ => Unit.Default)
.Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod());
```

Alternatively, apply the `SubscribeOn`/`ObserveOn` pattern to get off the current thread, perform work and then receive the results on the original thread.

```
myRepo.GetDataFromNetwork()
    .SubscribeOn(taskPoolScheduler)
    .ObserveOn(dispatcherScheduler)
    .Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod());
```

Comment: Adding one more point here... using the scheduler inside of a custom method breaks SRP entirely, and can also make testing more difficult. The method should be designed to *do* a thing, not know where it *should* be done. That's what the observable composition and orchestration is for.

Comment: Also, if there are multiple places in code which are invoking this method, just reroute that code so it uses the original scheduling. That's why we have operators like `Merge`. This gives us more fine-grain control.

Comment: Upvotes for this, testing Rx code is way easier when you use ObserveOn

Comment: To Christopher Harris' comment on SRP, some operators will need to Schedule, in which case they should take the scheduler as a paramter.

Comment: Also to Christopher's comment, I dont suggest anywhere here that this should be a custom operator. This is just a pattern to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally there is no difference. However I would use `ObserveOn(dispatcher)` and leave `SomeMethod()` as it is. You might also later be calling `SomeMethod()` from the UI thread in which case the dispatching would be be unnecessary. I would say it should be the responsibility of the calling code to know whether it is running on the UI thread or not and therefore whether dispatching is required.